# Maven remove specific artifacts / artifacts group from dependency:dependency-copy result

Tags: java, maven, packaging

I have to copy dependencies of some project excluding some of them. Exclusion is to be transitive. OK, this is the task `maven-dependency` handles without any problem. So far so good.

Next step I need to remove (filter out) some artifacts from all of this directory content. Only specific artifacts or better artifacts group. No transition. This is why I cannot join this with previous step.

Is it doable based on some popular maven plugin? Used maven is 3.x if it does matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define exclusions to maven dependencies. I hope this is what you are looking for.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1.GA</version>
        <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
            <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: OK, probably I really can move exclusion here as final artifact is just temporary thing not deployed and I don't need these dependencies for assembly. So dependency-copy can focus on more specific thing.

Comment: Accepting as best try to help. Final solution was to transitively exclude some dependency and then add their sub-dependencies directly. Works as barely acceptable solution.